# iOS 7 iPad Status bar in splash screen is hidden

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, ios-simulator

Have anyone met the same issue? Or have I missed something.

On my iOS 7 iPad simulator I can't see the status bar anymore.
It is visible in iOS 6 iPad though.

Is it a bug, or there is a setting to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status bar has been changed in `iOS7`. While the background is not visible by default you should still see its contents. It might be not visible if you are displaying black content above a black background but you can override this method for this: `- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle`.

I found this [article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/developers-guide-to-the-ios-7-status-bar/) recently about changes to consider on iOS7 for the status bar.